# Primitives in the union of 2 convex sets

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

If a holomorphic function has a primitive in 2 different domains, does this imply that the function will have a primitive in the union of the sets?
More precisely, I am not sure how to approach this question, as I know how to show that f has a primitive in U and also in , but not in their union:

Suppose that U, V ⊆ C are two open, convex sets and f : U ∪ V → C is holomorphic. Show that f has a primitive in U ∪ V .

Comment: It suffices to prove that $U\cup V$ is simply connected, which follows from Seifert-Van Kampen's theorem (since $U\cap V$, being convex, is path connected)

Comment: I have not covered this Theorem in my lectures yet but thank you